# wget with many pages

Tags: web, wget

The `-k` option in `wget` converts the links to local or remote, according to whether the file that is linked to is also downloaded. (See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Retrieval-Options) for more details)

Is it possible to use `wget` in this way: I download two webpages, say `www.example.com/1` and `www.example.com/2`, where the first page has a link to the second page, and `wget` converts the link to local, since the second page is also downloaded.

**NOTE**: I can't download `www.example.com/1` using a recursive option with depth 1, since `www.example.com/1` may have links to other pages, and I only want `www.example.com/2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
wget -kp www.example.com/1 www.example.com/2
```

From the site you linked:

> ‘-p’ ‘--page-requisites’ This option causes Wget to download all the
>   files that are necessary to properly display a given html page. This
>   includes such things as inlined images, sounds, and referenced
>   stylesheets.

Comment: That's two separate `wget`s, and I don't think the link from `www.example.com/1` to `www.example.com/2` will be converted to a local link.

Comment: Try that. I'm not sure you can do any better than that, at lest with wget.

Comment: I tried it, and it doesn't convert the link to local. Maybe we can't really do better than that, but I'm just curious :)

Comment: You could always finish it off with a sed :)

Comment: I'm gonna award the bounty, but it says I must wait 2 hours :)

Comment: Oh, when I said "Try that" I should have said "I updated it, Try that". Glad it worked out :).